# What exactly is a provider in silex?

Tags: php, silex

What is a service provider in silex? How does that differ from a service?

Why should one use a service provider in silex versus injecting your class into silex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service provider is a class that registers a service. It is used when it needs complex configuration or exposes multiple keys in your pimple DIC.

If your service registration is a single `return new Foo()` then by all means, do it in your bootstrap file. But if it's complex like the [Doctrine provider](https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Provider/DoctrineServiceProvider.php) it's best to keep separate.